# event.loaded показывает значение больше, чем весит сам файл

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, javascript-events

Пытаюсь написать прогрессбар загрузки файла на сервер, прогрессбар заполняется в зависимости от кол-ва уже загруженных байт на сервер от общего веса файла, но в итоге свойство `loaded` события `progress` показывает во много раз больше байт, чем весит сам файл, подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема

```
function sendForm() {
    event.preventDefault();
    xhr.open("POST", "https://netology-slow-rest.herokuapp.com/upload.php");
    xhr.send(formData);
    let file = form.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    let fileSize = file.files[0].size;
    xhr.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
        let kyloBytesLoaded = event.loaded;
        let percents = kyloBytesLoaded / fileSize;
        progress.value = percents ;
    });
}
```

Comment: "//перевожу байты в биты" - ??

Comment: там другое было, комент забыл удалить